# Having problems with timezone attribute on cron.yaml file in APP Engine Cron

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a problem with the timezone attribute. It throws an error as below.

"ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [/xxxxxxx/cron.yaml]
Unable to assign value 'America/Santiago' to attribute 'timezone':
timezone 'America/Santiago' is unknown
in "/xxxxxxx/cron.yaml", line 5, column 13"

I did a test with other timezone values that have the same result.

Current cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: "Get Storbox files fromt 7 days ago"
  url: /api/cron/storbox/read-files
  schedule: every day 02:30
  timezone: America/Santiago
  retry_parameters:
    job_retry_limit: 3
    job_age_limit: 1h
    min_backoff_seconds: 120
    max_doublings: 0

- description: "Send Storbox files"
  url: /api/cron/storbox/send-files
  schedule: every 30 minutes from 08:30 to 18:00
  timezone: America/Santiago
  retry_parameters:
    job_retry_limit: 1
    job_age_limit: 10m
    min_backoff_seconds: 120
    max_doublings: 0

- description: "Update UF value"
  url: /api/cron/uf
  schedule: every day 05:00
  timezone: America/Santiago
  retry_parameters:
    job_age_limit: 2h
    min_backoff_seconds: 45
    max_doublings: 1
```

The "America/Santiago" is not deprecated value from "zoneinfo" list.

I hope your help.

Regards

Comment: Sounds like a bug, and you should probably report it to Google.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with `gcloud 297.0`  which didn't let users to deploy their App Engine application properly. This issue affected zones within *America* and showed an Error message like the one posted on this question:

> Unable to assign value 'America/<city_name>' to attribute 'timezone':
>
> timezone 'America/<city_name>' is unknown

The Cloud SDK Engineering team from Google has fixed it and the recommendation is to upgrade your Cloud SDK version to version `297.0.1`. This fix is mentioned in their [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#29701_2020-06-17).

To see your current Cloud SDK version please use the command `gcloud components list`. If you would like to update your Cloud SDK version, run `gcloud components update`. For these actions, use [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update) as reference.

If you would like to take a deeper look of the issue, take a look at the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159109983) which was opened on June 16,2020.

If you are still experiencing this issue even after following the workarounds, please [Create a Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) or reach Support directly from your GCP project.

Hope this is helpful! :)

Comment: I updated SDK and it worked. Thank you!.

Comment: Awesome! If this answer helped you to solve the issue, please consider accepting it so other members from the community with similar questions can have more insight about this :)